Return specific text from a document
I'm coding up a little tool for my dnd group to automate some of the book keeping when we're playing more complex games like GURPS.
Basically what I need to know is if there's a way to return a specific section of text so that I can do operations with it.
So for example, if the doc says: HP 10/10
I want to be able to read the leftmost number like so: HP **10**/10
and return that number so I can do operations on it. So that if you took damage, I could run my script to find and automatically update the hp to 9/10 for example.
Finding and replacing the exact same text every time is pretty easy, but I have no idea how to locate and return an unknown value.
